# How to pass file upload details and others input in different model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5

resume model

```
public class Resume
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Binary { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Contact model

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
}
```

Student model

```
public class Student
{
    public List<Contact> Contacts{ get; set; }
    public List<Resumes> Resume{ get; set; }
}
```

this is View

```
@model SendAFaxWeb.Models.Student
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Contact.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Contact.Name)

        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Contact.ContactNumber)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Contact.ContactNumber)

        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Contact.Address)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Contact.Address)

         *//here should be upload resume, the detail will be save in Resumes model(name, binary, pageCount and path)*
        @Html.Label("Upload Resume")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.file, new { type = "file" })
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Submit(Student stud)
{
    //to save student details
}
```

Sorry for my bad English and I'm new in MVC development. My problem here is I don't know how to pass file with other data to controller. the controller expected *Student stud* have all data *Resumes* and *Contact*. How can I manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I consider your code as good practice: try add this to your Student class:

```
public HttpPostedFileBase FileToUpload { get; set;}
```

In View change the line:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FileToUpload, new { type = "file" })
```

Then In controller you can do this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Student model)
    {
var file= model.FileToUpload;
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) 
            {
                // extract only the filename
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
```

But, If you consider redesigning your code  which could lead you to better manageability, study about view model concept. Mr. Google can help you a lot. Hope this helps